# Set Tooltip to QwtPlotCurve

Tags: qt, tooltip, qwt

I am plotting a `QwtPlotCurve` like this :

```
QwtPlotCurve *qpc = new QwtPlotCurve();
    qpc->setSamples( QVector<double>::fromStdVector(x[i]), QVector<double>::fromStdVector(y[i]));
```

And then i attach this to a  `QwtPlot`.

I need to set a Tooltip to each Point of this `QwtPlotCurve`, how can i implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a built-in function for this but you can use a [QwtPlotMarker](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_marker.html) for this. Here are some code samples to be used within a mouse event of the plot

```
void showToolTip(QMouseEvent* ev){

    // get all curves
    QwtPlotItemList curves = qwtplot->itemList(QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotCurve);

    // works only for one curve, otherwise iterate over them and compare
    double distance = 1e99;
    int point_index = static_cast<QwtPlotCurve*>(curves[0])->closestPoint(QPoint(ev->x(), ev->y()), &distance);

    if(distance > _some_limit) { return; }
    QPointF p = static_cast<QwtPlotCurve*>(curves[0])->sample(point_index);

    QwtPlotMarker* tooltip = new QwtPlotMarker();
    tooltip->setLabel("X: "+QString::number(p.x())+" Y: "+QString::number(p.y()).c_str());
    tooltip->setXValue(p.x());
    tooltip->setYValue(p.y());
    tooltip->attach(qwtplot);
    qwtplot->replot();
}
```

Note: some variables are obviously missing, the code is just an example and will not compile by itself. Should be easy to adjust to your application

Comment: after several examples i notice that the point_index is constantly the same...no matter where i have the cursor.

Comment: How are you calling the function and how many curves do you have in your plot?

Comment: The function is called as a MouseEvent and i have  3 Curves.But i test it only for one and even if i click on a specific point it keeps giving me wrong point_index.

Comment: do you check all of the three curves? the given code works only for one (`curves[0]`) and you need to iterate over all of them. also check the mouse coordinates in a debugger. The method must of course be a mouse event of the plot widget

Comment: yes i understood what your code does.I click on a point so there is no reason to check all the curves but just the one that contains that point.Each time depending the point i choose to test i use the respective curve...

Comment: One more question @Bowdzone , How this can work with 3 curves tha i have.If i iterate i will have 3 closests points from each curve.Am i right?

Comment: you'd need to check each of those for the shortest distance to your mouse coordinates

Comment: ok i found why `closestPoint` is not working because `ev->x()` takes the coordinates from all the Dockwidget and is compared to qwtPlot points that have completely different values.So the question is if i can connect a MouseEvent only to a QwtPLot?